# Why does an open subset of reals with finite measure is bounded?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $A \subset \mathbb{ R}$ be open and have finite Lebesgue measure then it is bounded.

First, since $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$, it can be written as a countable union of disjoint open intervals. Let us write
$$ A = \cup_{i \geq 1} (a_i, b_i) $$
Where each $(a_i,b_i) $ is the said open interval. Clearly, none of these intervals can be infinite, otherwise it is contained in this union, hence $A$ and so $m(A)$ becomes infinite, which is not possible.

Now let us define $a:= \inf\{a_i : I \geq 1\}$ and $b := \sup\{b_i: i\geq 1\}$. We will be done if we have $ -\infty < a < b < \infty$. But I am not sure how to show that.

I will appreciate it if anyone has any suggestions on how to go on about showing this or have any other ways to show this result.

Thank you.

An idea: since none of these intervals can be unbounded on the left so maybe that’s why $a > -\infty$?

Edit: I feel so foolish for not looking for an example beforehand. Thank you everyone who commented, this problem is resolved now.

Comment: I would advise against trying to prove that.

Comment: What about $(0,1)\cup(1,\frac32)\cup(2,\frac94)\cup...$ ?  The measure is $2$ and the set is unbounded.

Comment: You mean there’s a counter example?

Comment: try to construct a counterexample by taking balls centered around $1,2,3,\dots$ with rapidly decreasing radii

Answer (score 0):

HINT.- It is easy to build a counterexample.

►Take an strictly increasing non bounded sequence $\{a_n\}$ and a sequence convergent to zero $\{\delta_n\}$.

►With the open set $\cup(a_n,a_n+\delta_n)$ you are done.

Comment: It takes more than for the $\delta_n$ to converge to zero. For example, if you take $\delta_n=\frac{1}{n}$, and $a_n=2n$, then the set has measure $\sum\frac{1}{n}=\infty$.  And you did not preclude negative or $0$ values for $\delta_n$. You need a sequence $\{\delta_n\}$ of *positive* numbers such that $\sum\delta_n\lt\infty$.